# Find the value of equation of four variables

Tags: linear-algebra

If $a,b,c$ and $d$ satisfy the equations: 
$$\begin{align}a+7b+3c+5d&=0 \\
8a+4b+6c+2d&=-16\\
2a+6b+4c+8d&=16 \\
5a+3b+7c+d&=-16 \end{align}$$

then find the value of $(a+d)(b+c)$

Comment: well u can simply do matrix elimination and find all the values

Comment: Do you want the complete derivation or only the final result?

Answer (score 1):

Let $s=a+d$ and $t=b+c$.

Adding the 2nd and 3rd equations gives $s+t=0$, and

Adding the 1st and 4th equations gives $3s+5t=-8$.

Solving gives $s=4$ and $t=-4$, so $st=-16$.

Answer (score 0):

Grab the nearest TI calculator and build the following $4\times 5$ matrix:

$$\begin{array}{ccccc}&1&7&3&5&0 \\
&8&4&6&2&-16\\
&2&6&4&8&16 \\
&5&3&7&1&-16\end{array}$$ We'll call this matrix "$A$". Next find the "$\text{rref}$" function on your calculator and calculate $\text{rref}(A)$ to get a matrix that looks like $$\begin{array}{ccccc}&1&0&0&0&x_1 \\
&0&1&0&0&x_2\\
&0&0&1&0&x_3 \\
&0&0&0&1&x_4\end{array}$$ This is called the *row reduced echelon form* (rref) of $A$, and that diagonal of $1$'s tells you all you need to know. If you don't have a calculator that can do this, I'm sure you can find an rref calculator online. When there is one $a$ in the first column in the first row, you are left with $x_1$. When there is one $b$ in the second column in the second row, you are left with $x_2$, etc. Anyway, that is to say that $a =x_1$, $b =x_2$, $c=x_3$ and $d=x_4$. You should be able to answer the rest of your question with that information.